# Android webView, displaying CSS correctly

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

I'm trying to display a webpage correctly in an Android webView. In the webView, the webpage defaults to its mobile version. The mobile version has a toolbar with a logo, nav icon (hamburger), and search bar.  The page loads correctly except for this toolbar; the whole bar is invisible. This being said, you can still click the nav icon and search bar and they function correctly.

I've tried tried injecting Javascript to fix the problem, but I'm not a web developer! and it doesn't seem to work:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            // This injection fixes CSS that occasionally doesn't display correctly
            // in the webView.
            String fixingJs = "$(\'header > div > a\').css({\"display\":\"inline\"});";                   
            view.loadUrl("javascript: "+fixingJs);
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue. Don't try to fix it in Javascript or java.